# Finding wav sounds for messages

Tags: notifications, wav

I am trying to find a good site with wav sounds preferebly free that i can use in messages of type.. Info, Warning, Critical and such.

Sadly so far most of the wav sound sites that i have encountered have irrelevant sounds for software development use.

Edit. Just to clarify, i am targeting .NET CF C#. I am aware of system sounds and looking for something more than that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should honour the sounds that the user has chosen in their selected theme e.g.

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

EDIT - Example is c# but all systems should have an equivilent API. This allows the user to choose the sounds they want to hear. Devising your own selection of noises is making needless work for yourself and may confuse or annoy.

Comment: Looks like your assuming C# and/or .Net

Comment: indeed i am. principle still applies, feel free to translate into your language of choice.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the sounds that are included in Windows by default? They have a whole set so that you can change the notification sounds yourself, so there should be plenty to choose from.

Comment: You assumed windows, what about *nix and mac?

Comment: I'm sure Gnome/KDE etc have their own APIs for playing system sounds?

Comment: Unkwntech: As sillymonkey said. I doubt that the Mac and Unix crowds have been going this entire time without sound notifications. If the OP is on one of those systems, he can look through those libraries as well, but in almost all likelihoods, he would want to focus on default Windows sounds because they would be the most recognizable to his end users.

Answer (score 0):

You could try freesound
http://www.freesound.org/

The license on most of those sounds is CC SA-BY 1.0 (noncommercial) I think... that's a problem in some cases (e.g. Fedora won't take non-commercial.)

You might also find something in here:
http://www.archive.org/details/audio

Answer (score -1):

You could always be a bit fancier and use some speech... http://www.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php